# Queue of action delegates not invoking correctly, why?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, delegates, action

I was trying to make a `Queue<Action>`. When I went to dequeue and invoke each action, it kept stopping at `4`. I walked through the code and it was processing everything correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

```c#
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass test = new SomeClass();
        test.EnqueuePrint("1");
        test.EnqueuePrint("2");
        test.EnqueuePrint("3");
        test.EnqueuePrint("4");
        test.EnqueuePrint("5");
        test.EnqueuePrint("6");
        test.EnqueuePrint("7");
        test.EnqueuePrint("8");
        Console.WriteLine("Process the queue!");
        test.ProcessQueue();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private Queue<Action> _actionQueue;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        _actionQueue = new Queue<Action>();
    }
    public void EnqueuePrint(string message)
    {
        _actionQueue.Enqueue(() => Print(message));
    }

    private void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void ProcessQueue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _actionQueue.Count; i++)
        {
            _actionQueue.Dequeue().Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Process the queue!
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I am interested in learning about the mental process which led to both this error and your inability to diagnose it without help. Did you for instance believe that the code was equivalent to `int c = q.Count; for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) ... ` ? I design automatic bug finders so it is helpful to me to understand the psychology behind a bug.

Comment: That's exactly it, I did not take into account the that the `_actionQueue.Count` variable was decreasing.... Plus no sleep :)

Comment: Hah, clearly I should take programmer sleepiness into account. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the count decreases as you dequeue items. So by the time `i` is 4, the count is *also* 4, so the loop stops.

If you want to keep dequeuing until the queue is empty, you could use:

```
while (_actionQueue.Count > 0)
{
    _actionQueue.Dequeue().Invoke();
}
```

Or if the action might (in other cases) add more items to the queue and you only want to process as many items as there were originally, you could use:

```
int originalCount = _actionQueue.Dequeue();
for (int i = 0; i < originalCount; i++)
{
    _actionQueue.Dequeue().Invoke();
}
```

Comment: @TheKobra It's worth noting that the `for` loop in your question will terminate when half of the delegates have been dequeued and executed.

Comment: This is the second time I've seen this bug on SO; I can't find the other one right now though.

Comment: Sometimes the hardest problems have the easiest answers >_<

Comment: @TheKobra: I am confused by your comment; in what sense is the problem hard if the answer is easy?